# How to see Java swing code in an IntellijIDEA project

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

In `File > Settings... > Gui Designer`, I checked the box to generate Java source code, but this is not what I meant. This effectively adds a function generated from the form file. In the generated code, there are many calls to IntellijIDEA's classes which I do not have the source code of.

I would like to have the entire source code of my project (including the swing code) so that it is not bound to a particular IDE. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure.  Stop using GUI designer and write the Swing GUI code by hand.  Read my [Java Swing File Browser](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=637) article to see how.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc You are right. I would have coded it by hand, but it is not my code.